# How to fix grid view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing batch editing functionality on kendo Grid. I have created kendo grid. After all, my problem is that when i try inline edit ,the whole cell become html cell. What's wrong with my code.
**view**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<webkendo.Models.ProductViewModel>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(product => product.ProductID).Width(50);
                columns.Bound(product => product.ProductName);
                columns.Bound(product => product.UnitsInStock).Width(50);
                columns.Command(commands =>
                {
                    commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items.
                }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Create(); // The "create" command adds new data items.
                toolbar.Save(); // The "save" command saves the changed data items.
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) // Use in-cell editing mode.
            .DataSource(dataSource =>
                dataSource.Ajax()
                .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates.
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(product => product.ProductID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model.
                    model.Field(product => product.ProductID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable.
                })
                .Create(create => create.Action("Products_Create", "Home")) // Action method invoked when the user saves a new data item.
                .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))  // Action method invoked when the grid needs data.
                .Update(update => update.Action("Products_Update", "Home"))  // Action method invoked when the user saves an updated data item.
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Products_Destroy", "Home")) // Action method invoked when the user removes a data item.
            )
            .Pageable()
)
```

**Onload**
 [image]

**when i try to edit inline**
[image]

How did it happen?

Comment: You have console errors or event handlers not shown?

Comment: No console error

Comment: Which browser, add-ins and kendo version are you seeing this in ? Does it happen in all cells or just `product name` ? What are the hints, if any, for the `ProductViewModel` ?

Comment: it happen in every cell when i type and same result in every browsers